# Разделение в блоге пользователей по ролям

Tags: javascript, html, css, блог

Люди, пишу самый простой блог на html, css, js и node js. Смотрю на примеры различные и понимаю, что во многих блогах нет авторизации/регистрации. Но как тогда происходит разделение по ролям (на админа и юзеров)? Админ же должен создавать новые посты, редактировать и удалять старые. А задача пользователей только читать посты. Но авторизации/регистрации нет, и как тогда там создаются/редактируются посты админом? Программно?

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что авторизации там нет?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не было "войти" или "зарегистрироваться"

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот [например](https://andythemoron.com/) или [вот](http://ignorethecode.net/blog/)

Comment: @BearVorkuta, где угодно это где?

Comment: @Alex чтобы отредактировать или удалить пост, не обязательно заходить на саму страницу блога. Если все данные подгружаются из какой либо БД, просто нужно иметь к ней доступ. Админка (страничка) вполне может лежать в какой нибудь другой папке с другим именем.

Answer (score -1):

Возможно, что регистрация для админов есть, но находится по какому-нибудь http://your.blog.com/hidden-registration-for-admins. Все, кто зарегистрирован - админы, а остальные пользователи. Вот и разделение. Но это, конечно, пример. На деле может быть всё, что угодно.